# Read all the numbers from line of file

Tags: freepascal

On the first line of `data.txt` I have two numbers separated by space.

How do I read / output to the screen each number?

**This is my code so far which reads only the first number of the line.**

```
program p1;
uses crt;
  const filename = 'data.txt';
  var 
   cv : integer;
   myfile: text;
   i,sum:integer;
begin 
    i:=0;
    sum:=0;
    Assign(myfile, filename);
    Reset(myfile);
    while not (Eof(myfile)) do
      begin
        while not eoln(myfile) do begin
          Readln(myfile, cv);
          Writeln(cv); 
        end;
      end;
    close(myfile);
end.
```

**This is my `data.xt` file :**

```
4 10
250  
350  
400 
1000
```

I can't get to that `10` on the first line,

Comment: Read the line. Split the string on spaces. Pick the second item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do it, but the one closest to what you have already is to remove the inner loop and use READ instead of READLN.  Like so:

```
program p1;
uses crt;
const filename = 'data.txt';
var
  cv : integer;
  myfile: text;
begin
  Assign(myfile, filename);
  Reset(myfile);
  while not (Eof(myfile)) do begin
    Read(myfile, cv);
    Writeln(cv);
  end;
  close(myfile);
end.
```